# mysql query in laravel without ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

How can write only mysql query in Laravel (5.3)

This query is working in version mysql >= 5.6, but in my server mysql 5.5:

```
DB::table('categories')
    ->leftJoin('data', 'categories.id', '=', 'data.categories_id')
    ->select('categories.*',  DB::raw("count(data.categories_id) as 
video_count"))
    ->groupBy('categories.id')
    ->get();
```

I need to write like this

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM ....");
```

Comment: Change `get()` for `toSql()` and you’ll get the raw SQL query.

Comment: I found the answer myself
DB::select("SELECT COUNT(`data`.categories_id) AS data_count, categories.*  FROM categories LEFT JOIN `data` ON (`data`.categories_id = categories.id) GROUP BY categories.id");